# neo4j Neo.ClientError.Transaction.TransactionHookFailed

Tags: neo4j

I was trying to change a property to a node using

```
MATCH (n:User) where n.firstname = 'Mark' set n.school = 'MIT' return n
```

but I got this error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Transaction.TransactionHookFailed
```

Why are we getting this error? The neo4j documentation does not contain any explanation for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `merge`

```
MATCH (n:User) 
  where n.firstname = 'Mark' 
merge n.school = 'MIT' ;
```

you won't have any return, you should re query using `match ... return`

as per https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/ §merge

> Match a pattern or create it if it does not exist. Use ON CREATE and ON MATCH for conditional updates.

```
MERGE (n:Person {name: $value})
  ON CREATE SET n.created = timestamp()
  ON MATCH SET
    n.counter = coalesce(n.counter, 0) + 1,
    n.accessTime = timestamp()
```

Comment: Hmmm. The syntax of the `MERGE` clause in the first query is illegal. And `MERGE` has no obvious applicability to this issue. Can someone clarify why this is a valid answer?

Comment: Well this is the syntax I've been using for two years now. I'll confirm `cyphershell`/`neo4j` version latter on. And OP accepted the answer, so I'll expect he tries it.

Comment: Your first query generates a SyntaxError in neo4j 3.5.12 (and 4.0.0). If it works or you, I'd be curious what version of neo4j you are running (and also what that `MERGE` syntax is supposed to do).

Comment: 1) as for version I am running **3.4.3**. 2) second merge syntax set value depending on creation of node or matching merging note. See **merge** section on the link.

Comment: @cybersam  I see now `match ... merge` is not mention in refcard, I'll have to check if I use it.